# javascript unicode connection with html

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, encoding

I have a program that converts binary/morse/hex to ASCII but for some reason the output to the dom shows squares.
I'm assuming it's because it doesn't know how to interpret the characters.

I don't know how to get javascript to show the right characters. In the console it gives the correct response but as soon as I send it to the DOM it shows those dreaded boxes.

Firstly I would like to know why the console is showing the correct output but the DOM doesn't, and secondly how to I get the DOM to show the correct output.

I tried changing the HTML encoding to UTF-16 but that didn't work. I'm using chrome. here is a small piece of the program

```js
if (baseButton.textContent == "morse") {
  const get = await fetch("morse.json") //this gets the morse from a JSON file
  const morseData = await get.json()
  const keys = Object.keys(morseData);
  const values = Object.values(morseData);
  let morseArray = secretMessage.split(' ') // this is the morse/binary/hex... from an input in html
  let string = ''

  for (let i = 0; i < morseArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
      if (morseArray[i] == values[j]) string += keys[j]
    }
  }
  console.log(string) //this gives the correct output in the console
  output.textContent = string.replace(/  /g, " ") // this shows boxes in the DOM
} // output is displayed in the HTML below
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <span>result:</span>
  <p>
    <pre id="code"></pre>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to provide a [mcve]. Change `const morseData = await get.json()` to an actual example of data

Comment: Also add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the head of the web page

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from the code you show - we need to see your object,
The binary likely isn't stringified

But for morse this is simpler - I used _ as space

```js
const secretMessage = ".... . .-.. .-.. --- _ .-- --- .-. .-.. -..";
const a2morse = {"_": "_", "a":".-","b":"-...","c":"-.-.","d":"-..","e":".","f":"..-.","g":"--.","h":"....","i":"..","j":".---","k":"-.-","l":".-..","m":"--","n":"-.","o":"---","p":".--.","q":"--.-","r":".-.","s":"...","t":"-","u":"..-","v":"...-","w":".--","x":"-..-","y":"-.--","z":"--.."};
const morse2a = Object.keys(a2morse).reduce((acc,cur) => {
  acc[a2morse[cur]] = cur
  return acc
},{})

let str = secretMessage.split(" ").map(l => `${morse2a[l]}`).join("")
console.log(str) //this gives the correct output in the console
document.getElementById('output').textContent = str
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```